# How to clear all data in a listBox?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, listbox

I am after a statement that will clear all strings / data that is currently in a listBox, I have tried:

```
private void cleanlistbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.ResetText();
}
```

Comment: 6 answers, and they're all the same. There should be a `Participated in a choir` badge. :-)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

What about

```
listbox1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Lol, should have thought of that myself :(

Comment: Grats on your first "Nice Answer" badge!

Comment: @Yuck - Thanks, I'm surprised I was the first to answer.

Comment: This doesn't work if the DataSource is set. Sadly clearing the DataSource (in my case a BindingList) also doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

If it is bound to a Datasource it will throw an error using  `ListBox1.Items.Clear();`

In that case you will have to clear the Datasource instead. e.g., if it is filled with a Datatable:

```
  _dt.Clear();   //<-----Here's the Listbox emptied.
  _dt = _dbHelper.dtFillDataTable(_dt, strSQL);

  lbStyles.DataSource = _dt;
  lbStyles.DisplayMember = "YourDisplayMember";
  lbStyles.ValueMember = "YourValueMember";
```

Comment: I had to set the DataSource to null and then to my list, it was not picking up the change in the list otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

**Try this:**

```
 private void cleanlistbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     listBox1.DataSource = null;
     listBox1.Items.Clear();
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
private void cleanlistbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 5):

this should work:

```
private void cleanlistbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear( );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
private void cleanlistbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CListBox as pointer (*) use this line:
pList1->ResetContent();

Answer (score 0):

If your listbox is connected to a LIST as the data source, listbox.Items.Clear() will not work.

I typically create a file named "DataAccess.cs" containing a separate class for code that uses or changes data pertaining to my form.  The following is a code snippet from the DataAccess class that clears or removes all items in the list "exampleItems"

```
public List<ExampleItem> ClearExampleItems()
       {
           List<ExampleItem> exampleItems = new List<ExampleItem>();
           exampleItems.Clear();
           return examplelistItems;
        }
```

ExampleItem is also in a separate class named "ExampleItem.cs"

```
using System;

namespace        // The namespace is automatically added by Visual Studio
{
    public class ExampleItem
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

        public string FullExampleItem 
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{ItemId} {ItemType} {ItemNumber} {ItemDescription}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code for your Window Form, the following code fragments reference your listbox:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace        // The namespace is automatically added by Visual Studio
{
    
    public partial class YourFormName : Form
    {
        
        List<ExampleItem> exampleItems = new List<ExampleItem>();

        public YourFormName()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Connect listbox to LIST
            UpdateExampleItemsBinding();
        }

        private void UpdateUpdateItemsBinding()
        {
            ExampleItemsListBox.DataSource = exampleItems;
            ExampleItemsListBox.DisplayMember = "FullExampleItem";
        }

        private void buttonClearListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
            exampleItems = db.ClearExampleItems();
            
            UpdateExampleItemsBinding();
        }
    }
}
```

This solution specifically addresses a Windows Form listbox with the datasource connected to a list.

Answer (score -1):

In C# Core DataSource does not exist, but this work fine:

```
listbox.ItemsSource = null;
listbox.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Maybe I would change the order of the both commands. So first `Clear()` then the `null` assignment